# R: reshape and dcast confusion

Tags: r, reshape2

Having worked on this for a few hours, and looking through all the `dcast` answers and tutorials I could find. I think I'd better ask instead.

Example data first:

```
xx = data.frame(SOIL = c(rep("kraz", 20), (rep("sodo", 20))),
                DM = runif(0, 20,n=40),
                cutnum = c(rep(1:4,10)))
```

Now, the required operation. I'd like to end up with a table with `Soil` names on the row, and `Cutnum` as column names, with the `DM` values in the columns under the `cutnumbers`.

```
# Soil  1   2   3   4
# kraz  1.2 19  12.1    9.9
# kraz  15.3    4.5 9.2 12.1
# kraz  14  15.2    5.2 15.4
# kraz  18.5    0.7 14.3    5
# kraz  17.1    15.8    2.9 9.5
# kraz  13  14.4    4.9 8.6
# kraz  3   10.2    3.5 14
# kraz  17.7    8.6 10.6    16.1
# kraz  12.6    1.7 2.2 17.5
# kraz  3.8 16.7    4.8 0.4
# kraz  4.1 17.1    12.5    14.5
# kraz  17.8    5.2 11.2    9.5
# kraz  12.3    2.2 4.8 8.7
# kraz  7.3 3   10.2    1.6
# kraz  11.3    12.2    13.4    10.2
# kraz  7.5 15.9    8.9 18.3
# kraz  15  5   19.6    16.5
# sodo  8.4 2.6 18.3    15.1
# sodo  6.9 19.7    6.5 8.4
# sodo  4   6.5 4.2 11.9
# sodo  0.8 12  18.3    15.4
# sodo  7.2 11.9    6.7 4.7
# sodo  2.6 4.4 13.8    13.7
# sodo  11.3    16.4    12.3    9.6
# sodo  5.6 17.1    11.4    16.7
# sodo  10.4    4.7 5.7 10.6
# sodo  8.7 5.6 1.1 4.8
# sodo  19.2    14.8    7   7
# sodo  18.6    9   14.9    5
# sodo  4.3 2.4 0.3 11.1
# sodo  4.9 18.4    19.5    9.7
# sodo  18.8    3.3 15.9    12.7
# sodo  19.7    0.1 13.6    3
# sodo  11.3    11.1    6.6 9.5
# sodo  8.1 11.3    10.1    3.5
# sodo  14.1    13.5    0.5 17.2
# sodo  16.8    15.6    16.2    17.3
```

I've tried:

```
require(reshape2)
dcast(xx, formula = SOIL ~ Cutnum, value.var = xx$DM)
```

Which produces the following:

```
Error: value.var (18.943128376267911.662011714652217.372458190657214.7615862498069.991016136482364.527641483582569.107870771549641.0582387680187810.695438273251115.275471545755917.17561007011680.9180781804025171.6045100009068812.556012449786118.57340626884257.465867823921144.576288489624868.3055530954152315.88032039348041.3668353855609916.888091783039310.544018512591714.95763068087410.46029578894380.95387450419366410.41133180726329.8472668603062618.449066961184111.24195748940114.0428098617121613.89849389437598.8408243283629416.336669707670818.53340925183156.113082133233555.875797253102060.06016504485160119.295095484703784.955938421189798.97169086616486) not found in input
In addition: Warning message:
In if (!(value.var %in% names(data))) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I'd greatly appreciate a suggestion that will get a more useful result.

Comment: Is your expected output correct? Where is `sodo` soil? Also, are you looking for `dcast(xx, formula = SOIL ~ Cutnum, mean, value.var = "DM")`?

Comment: @Pascal, error remains if you correct that...if I can see how to edit the question, I'll fix it.

Comment: You need a string as value.var, it doesn't take a vector.

Comment: @Pascal -- that just produces another error.  It does not find the DM values...it uses something else.

Comment: @Heroka...how do you implement that given my answer to Pascal... His suggestion produces :  SOIL 1 2 3 4
1 kraz 5 5 5 5
2 sodo 5 5 5 5

Comment: I think the main issue here is a typo in dcast it uses `cutnum`  instead of `Cutnum`.

Comment: It works for me, without error. And with `Cutnum`, not `cutnum`, as I explicitly wrote in my comment.

Comment: @bdecaf  it does not fix it. Just edited the question. I'll try restarting R.

Comment: If I use value.var as suggested by Pascal it works for me as well. Fixed the typo in the question.

Comment: Restarted, it gives the same  response. It seems to be just counting the number of values of each (5). First off all it only tabulates 8 values (there are 40), and they are all the value "5" ... which have nothing to do with the DM values (random numbers from 0 to 20).  So it is no working. What is the output you are getting?

Comment: @user2449710 : There are multiple rows in `xx` with the same `SOIL` and `Cutnum`, do you want the mean of `DM` or each set of `Cutnum` in a separate row?

Comment: @user2282381 , actually I am just after the data in wide form -- each DM value for each cutnum in a separate row -- with the soil name on the left. No aggregation or function application.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments, it seems OP requires a wide format ordered by the row with no function aggregation.
This should do it,

```
set.seed(123)    
xx = data.frame(SOIL = c(rep("kraz", 20), (rep("sodo", 20))),
                DM = runif(0, 20,n=40),
                cutnum = c(rep(1:4,10)))
require(reshape2)

xx$t <- rep(1:10, each=4) # Add column to identify subset
dcast(xx, SOIL+t~cutnum, value.var="DM")[, -2] # Remove new column
```